# Basic Authentication With Different Installs

Tags: android, authentication, basic-authentication

The app I am creating uses a phone number to authenticate. For the authentication we use

phoneNumber:password for the basic authentication header. At the moment this same password is used for users on multiple devices.

We now need to support multiple devices. So we are thinking of assigning a new password for each number.

Does it make sense to do it this way? Should we have a UserId and user this on every installation regardless of the phonenumber? Should we have a new password for each installation/each user/each phone number?

Answer (score 0):

This has absoulutely everything to do with what the app does. Do you want to share data between devices? You should probably have a login with Facebook, Google, and username/pass (support all of the above) so all of your users can log in, and have the same account. You can then assign phone numbers to the account.

If you want separate data for different platforms, then of course use the phone number as the user identification.

Comment: we don't need to identify the app from the phonenumber

Comment: Alright, then use my suggestion to use a username and password, and store a array of phone numbers for the user.

Comment: I will happily mark the question as correct if you could put some reasons for this?

Comment: If you're using the same account across multiple devices, obviously you don't want to log in with a phone number, as linking of the accounts will be difficult. Rather, you want to use an auth method that will be the same between the two devices. That way, the information is shared and there's no chance you will get into the wrong account.